# Terraform - How to lauch ec2 with a private AMI that has encrypted root device

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to launch ec2 with our firm's private AMIs (which are mandatory). These have root device 'encrypted'. If I try to launch with a public AMI, the script works fine and the ec2 is launched. But we are supposed to be using only the private AMIs. Any idea on what the config should look like for TF? Couldn't find any examples on the net. Most of them about 'creating' AMIs. I need code for 'using' pvt AMIs with encrypted root device. Thanks!

Comment: You would probably need to have access to KMS keys that were used to encrypt the EBS volume in the first place, with the permissions for decryption. You can find more information here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-share-encrypted-amis-across-accounts-to-launch-encrypted-ec2-instances/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to the site to update the answer I got through aws support. @MarkoE, the link you shared also has the solution. Thank you!! For those who want to get this done, you need to add these in a policy and attach to the role that is executing TF:
"kms:DescribeKey",   "kms:ReEncrypt*",   "kms:CreateGrant", "kms:Decrypt". The policy format can be found in MarkoE's comment above.